# Django regex url not working

Tags: python, regex, django

The `http://127.0.0.1:8000/song/299d8fe1-7d9f-434a-ba64-94fb7a16b1a6/`gives me the desired page based on the uuid of the song and works fine.
(It's the second url.)

Here is the urls.py

```
    urlpatterns = patterns('',
        url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
        url(r'^song/(?P<uuid>\S+)/$', views.song, name='song'),
-->     url(r'^song/(?P<uuid>\S+)/song_info/$', views.song_info, name='song_info'),
    )
```

The third url,

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/song/299d8fe1-7d9f-434a-ba64-94fb7a16b1a6/song_info/
```

the one the arrow is pointing at, gives me a 404 error, with the message "No Song matches the given query."

I'm guessing there's an error with the regex, but I can't figure it out.

**EDIT**

Here are the views for both the song and song info:

views.py

```
    imports....

    @login_required
    def song(request, uuid):
        song = get_object_or_404(Song, uuid=uuid)
        song_status = song.get_status()
        form = SongInfoForm(initial={'song_info': song.song_info}, user=request.user)

        return render(request, 'songapp/song.html',
            {'form': form, 'song': song, 'song_status': song_status})

    def song_info(request):
        return render(request, 'songapp/song_info.html')
```

Comment: url(r'^song/(?P<id>[a-zA-Z0-9]{0,30}[^/]+)/song_info/$

Comment: I think, after edit box/ to song/ there should be no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\S+` matches any sequence of characters, including '/'. So your second regex is matching the entire string of "299d8fe1-7d9f-434a-ba64-94fb7a16b1a6/song_info/" as the UUID parameter, and sending it to `views.song`, which unsurprisingly does not find a matching song.

You should make your regexes more discriminating:

```
url(r'^song/(?P<uuid>[\w-]+)/$', views.song, name='song'),
url(r'^song/(?P<uuid>[\w-]+)/song_info/$', views.song_info, name='song_info'),
```

Also, you should usually put your regexes in order of more specific to more general; Django matches in order, so if you had put song_info first that would also have solved your problem.

Comment: TypeError at /song/299d8fe1-7d9f-434a-ba64-94fb7a16b1a6/song_info/,  song_info() got an unexpected keyword argument 'uuid'

Comment: Well, does the `song_info` view take a UUID argument?

Comment: I'm officially embarrassed. Can't believe I missed that. Yeah it works now thanks a bunch.

Answer (score -1):

you should use this url

```
url(r'^song/(?P<id>[a-zA-Z0-9]{0,30}[^/]+)/song_info/$
```

Here, [^/] represents any type of  character but /, and the + right after matches this class of character one or more times. You do not want the final / to be in the uuid var, so put it outside the parentheses

Comment: Tried it and it still returns the same 404 error, "No Box matches the given query."